# Using perform_create to create an object that has ForeignKey in Django + django rest framework

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have The following code snippet in models.py :

```
class Supervisor(models.Model):
    emp_id = models.ForeignKey(Employee, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.supervisor)
```

In my views I have done :

```
class SupervisorAPIView(mixins.CreateModelMixin, generics.ListAPIView):

    """
        Add  Supervisor 
    """

  # permission_classes = (permissions.DjangoObjectPermissions,)
    lookup_field = 'pk'
    # permission_classes = (permissions.DjangoObjectPermissions,)
    serializer_class = SupervisorSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Supervisor.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(
            emp_id=self.kwargs['pk'])



  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

How do I use `perform_create()` to create the supervisor object ?

Comment: You want to nested create a Employee object?

Comment: Why you want to create method `perform_create()` that would hold all objects? You wish to use this `Supervisor.objects.all()` and use it for different OOP actions, if not, then why you dont create `def __init__(self): self.supervisorObjects = Supervisor.objects.all()` it will create all objects withing this `SupervisorAPIView` class and you will be able to use this `self.supervisorObjects` in wherever you need.